# Store a big String in database?

Tags: java, sql-server, hibernate

What is the best way to store a a big String in SQL server Database.

I'm using `varchar(8000)` but I get this exception while persisting my Object using Hibernate :

```
>Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

Comment: use varchar(max)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to store a very big string on `SQL Server` you can use:

```
 varchar(max)
```

Comment: I did this : ALTER TABLE myTable
ALTER COLUMN myVolumn varchar(8000); But still get the same exception.

Comment: @Oviic You're changing the column to the same datatype `varchar(8000)`, of course you're going to get same error.

Answer (score 3):

Which version of SQL Server are you using? If the version is above 2005 Use `VARCHAR(MAX)`. If the version is before 2005 you can use `TEXT`

Comment: If the OP is using SQL Server 2005, I suggest they upgrade, and then use `varchar(MAX)`! 2005 has been out of support for quite a while, and `text` is deprecated.

Comment: Can we just have [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) pinned somewhere? it tells people to not use text,ntext and image as they will be removed, I see people suggesting these types far too often, downvoted due to the suggestion

Answer (score 1):

Well as I can see the tag of hibernate you need the tag of `@Lob` for storing super large objects.

> Specifies that a persistent property or field should be persisted as a
>   large object to a database-supported large objec

Example:

```
@Lob @Basic(fetch=LAZY)
   @Column(name="REPORT")
   protected String report;
```

From [Hibernate Docs.](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/jpa/2.1/api/javax/persistence/Lob.html)